# conditional checking on string.split

Tags: actionscript-3

Can we do a conditional checking on `string.split()` method?

what we want to achieve is split a string into array at places wherever **"%"** is found but do not split at places **"#%#"** in the same string. Is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this using [`String.indexOf()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#indexOf%28%29):

```
if(string.indexOf("#%#") > -1)
{
    // This runs when #%# is found.
}
else
{
    // A lone % was found.
}
```

Key information:

> Searches the string and returns the position of the first occurrence of val found at or after startIndex within the calling string. This index is zero-based, meaning that the first character in a string is considered to be at index 0--not index 1. **If val is not found, the method returns -1**.

If what you actually mean is that you want to split the string *even if there is `#%#` contained within it*, but just not split unless it's a lone `%`, you can use Regular Expressions in your `.split()`:

```
string.split(/%(?!#)/);
```

Comment: Thanks. actually the string i am trying to split has both "%" and "#%#".

Comment: @ntidote Your questions says that you do not want to split a string that contains `#%#`...

Comment: @ntidote To split at both `%` and `#%#` you can use: `string.split(/%|#%#/);`